# Manipulate images with ImageMagick library in codeigniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I hope you guys can help me go further with my code, because i'm stuck. I totally confused my self while writing this code so i need a little bit of help, what is possible in current implementation and what is not.

So here is my Codeigniter code which uploads images and tries to manipulate with those files.

```
    public function addImagesToProduct_post(){
        $id_product = $this->input->post('id_product');

        $data = array();
        $count = count($_FILES['files']['size']);
        foreach($_FILES as $key=>$value) {
            for ($s = 0; $s <= $count - 1; $s++) {
                $_FILES['userfile']['name'] = $value['name'][$s];
                $_FILES['userfile']['type'] = $value['type'][$s];
                $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$s];
                $_FILES['userfile']['error'] = $value['error'][$s];
                $_FILES['userfile']['size'] = $value['size'][$s];
                $config['upload_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/images/";
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
                $config['max_width'] = 1920;
                $config['max_height'] = 1080;
                $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                if($this->upload->do_upload()){
                    $currentImage = $this->upload->data();
                    $this->load->library('image_lib');
                    $imgConfig['image_library'] = 'ImageMagick';
                    $imgConfig['source_image']  = $currentImage['full_path'];
                    $imgConfig['create_thumb']  = TRUE;
                    $imgConfig['thumb_marker']  = TRUE;
                    $imgConfig['maintain_ratio']= TRUE;
                    $imgConfig['width']         = 1024;
                    $imgConfig['wm_text'] = 'MY watermark';
                    $imgConfig['wm_font_size'] = '32';
                    $imgConfig['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
                    $imgConfig['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'right';
                    $imgConfig['wm_padding'] = '20';
                    $imgConfig['wm_type'] = 'text';
                    $this->image_lib->initialize($imgConfig);
                    $this->image_lib->watermark();
                    ///////////////////////////
                    //// SAVE STUFF TO DB /////
                    ///////////////////////////
                    $data['imgData'] = $this->upload->data();
                    $data['success'] = true;
                }else{
                    $data['messageErrorAddPicture'] = str_replace("<p>", '', str_replace("</p>", '', $this->upload->display_errors()));
                    $data['addImageFail'] = true;
                    $data['success'] = false;
                }
                echo json_encode($data);
            }
        }
        //echo json_encode($data);    
    }
```

My goals (write if its possible in my current implementation and provide example please):
 1. Upload image, not bigger then HD
 2. Compress current uploaded image to be less then 100kb
 3. Change size of image to max width 1024 x 786 (but what happens if user takes picture which is vertically positioned???)
 4. Create thumbnail of current image
 5. Set thumb image size of 250 x 250
 6. Place it under thumb folder (which is inside images folder)

My problems are:
 1. How to compress current image to be less then 100kb?
 2. If i resize current image to 1024 width, how to deal with vertical images?
 3. How to specify thumbnail size and store position location?

If you need any additional info, please let me know and i will provide. Thank you in advance

Comment: The additional info we need is: a precise definition of the problem.

Comment: i have updated a question with my problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to make it working.
This is how my controller looks like now

```
public function addImagesToProduct_post(){
    $id_product = $this->input->post('id_product');
    $prod = $this->Model_products->get($id_product);
    $prodImages = json_decode($prod[0]->images, true);
    $imgLastPosition = count($prodImages);

    $data = array();
    $count = count($_FILES['files']['size']);
    foreach($_FILES as $key=>$value) {
        for ($s = 0; $s <= $count - 1; $s++) {
            $_FILES['userfile']['name'] = $value['name'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['type'] = $value['type'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['error'] = $value['error'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['size'] = $value['size'][$s];
            $config['upload_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/images/products/";
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
            $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            if($this->upload->do_upload()){
                $currentImage = $this->upload->data();
                $this->load->library('image_lib');
                $this->resize_big_image($currentImage['full_path'], $currentImage['file_name']);
                $this->resize($currentImage['full_path'], $currentImage['file_name']);
                $newImage['id_image'] = $imgLastPosition;
                $newImage['thumbImage'] = '/home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html/images/products/'.
                        $currentImage['raw_name'].'_thumb'.$currentImage['file_ext'];
                $newImage['thumbName'] = $currentImage['raw_name'].'_thumb'.$currentImage['file_ext'];
                $newImage['image'] = '/home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html/images/products/large'.
                        $currentImage['raw_name'].$currentImage['file_ext'];
                $newImage['imageName'] = $currentImage['raw_name'].$currentImage['file_ext'];
                $newImage['position'] = $imgLastPosition;
                array_push($prodImages, $newImage);
                $data['imgData'] = $prodImages;
                $this->Model_products->updateProductImages($id_product, json_encode($prodImages));
                $data['success'] = true;
            }else{
                $data['messageErrorAddPicture'] = str_replace("<p>", '', str_replace("</p>", '', $this->upload->display_errors()));
                $data['addImageFail'] = true;
                $data['success'] = false;
            }
        }
        $imgLastPosition++;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}

private function resize_big_image($path, $file){
    $config['image_library']    = 'GD2';
    $config['source_image']     = $path;
    $config['maintain_ratio']   = TRUE;
    $config['master_dim']   = 'auto';
    $config['quality']  = '70%';
    $config['width'] = 1024;
    $config['height'] = 768;
    $config['new_image'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/images/products/large/" . $file;
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();

    $config['source_image'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/images/products/large/" . $file;
    $config['wm_text'] = 'My page';
    $config['wm_type'] = 'text';
    $config['wm_font_path'] = './system/fonts/texb.ttf';
    $config['wm_font_size'] = '32';
    $config['wm_font_color'] = '000000';
    $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
    $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'right';
    $config['wm_padding'] = '250';
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    $this->image_lib->watermark();

}

private function resize($path, $file) {
    $config['image_library']    = 'GD2';
    $config['source_image']     = $path;
    $config['create_thumb']     = TRUE;
    $config['maintain_ratio']   = false;
    $config['thumb_marker']     = '_thumb';
    $config['master_dim']   = 'auto';
    $config['width'] = 242;
    $config['height'] = 242;
    $config['new_image'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/images/products/" . $file;
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
}
```